# Matches dates in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, time

I have $startdate and $finishdate, and in one table in Mysql, two columns "start_date" and "finish_date".

I want to know if the first range ($startdate,$finishdate) it matches in some date with the second range ("start_date,"finish_date").

I tried with Between, but with Eloquent is different, and not working for me.

Comment: define `matches`

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the 2 ranges overlap?

Comment: Yes. For more explanation. I have a range to days of Vacations. I save it in a table with a range of dates. I don´t want repeat days of vacations in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you want to check if the 2 ranges overlap (a solution here but not tested):

```
if ($startdate<= "finish_date") and ("start_date" <= $finishdate)
```